# How to call a specific parent constructor using Lambda?

Tags: java, lambda

I am aware of the procedure to use the lambda expression to call the single arg constructor . But not sure how to invoke a constructor with additional arguments (not single arg). This can be achieved by using anonymous inner class as denoted in "[How to call a specific parent constructor from anonymous inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807148/how-to-call-a-specific-parent-constructor-from-anonymous-inner-class)" . But I am more interested in using the lambda expression.

For example: For calling the single arg constructor in Thread class, i can do this

```
Thread t1 = new Thread (() -> {
    //do sometask

});
```

But I could not find a similar way to call the Thread(String name) constructor.

basically I want to do something like below using lambda

```
Thread t2 = new Thread("Thread2") {
        @Override
        public void run() {                
        }

    };
```

Any help here is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Your example is not clear. It is not calling a zero-args constructor of Thread - it calls a constructor with a single Runnable argument. And why would you need a lambda expression to call the Thread(String name) constructor? `String` is not a functional interface.

Comment: Your example is calling the public Thread(Runnable target) where runnable is the functional interface and because of that, you are able to use lambda in constructor.

Comment: @Eran - Sorry for the confusion, edited the question now

Comment: It seems as if what you actually want is the two-argument constructor-- `Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> { doSomeTask(); }, "Thread1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread t1 = new Thread (() -> {
    //do sometask

}, "ThreadName");
```

Comment: This answers the question in the body, but not "How to call a specific parent constructor using Lambda?"

Comment: @slim I think the title the OP meant to use was "How to call a specific parent constructor with Lambda as parameter?" which is closer to the question that was actually asked.

Comment: @tobias_k I felt the code was fairly self-explanatory, and apparently the OP agrees.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand the question but if you want to use lambda and string constructor something like this should work:

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("in "), "Thread2")
```

Because the constructor in Thread class looks like:

```
 public Thread(Runnable target, String name)
```

So as the first argument you can use lambda expression (functional interface) and the second argument is the name of the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is not simply calling a constructor. It is defining an anonymous subclass of `Thread`, and calling its constructor.

```
Thread t2 = new Thread("Thread2") {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         // do something                
    }

};
```

Equivalent to:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         // do something                
    }
}

Thread t2 = new MyThread("Thread2");
```

So it is defining "stuff" about the new object in two ways:

1. By passing the "Thread2" to the constructor
2. By defining a subclass with an overridden method

A lambda can be used as an anonymous subclass (of a `class`) or implementation (of an `interface`) if the type is a *functional interface*, for example `Callable`:

```
Callable<Foo> r = () -> doSomething();
```

But `Thread` is not a functional interface -- it does not have exactly one abstract method --  so you can't do this for `Thread`.

For the specific case you have, `Thread` has a two argument constructor, so you don't need to create a subclass.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread( () -> someMethod(), "Thread1");
```