# Throwing an exception from an anonymous inner class's constructor

Tags: java, exception, constructor, anonymous-inner-class, throws

How do I add "throws" to an anonymous inner class's constructor?

```
class Foo {
  public Foo() throws Exception {
  }
}
```

Becasue this doesn't work

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Foo x = new Foo() {
     @Override
     public Foo() throws Exception {
     }
   }
 }
```

I'm trying to figure out where to put the "throws" to suppress the compiler warning. Is there a way to do this without using a try/catch block or making a separate class?

Comment: Accidentally hit enter before I finished typing, and I already got -2.

Comment: Yep, sometimes people slap you here faster and more frequently than you'd expect, frequently without telling you why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing constructor of an anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362424/accessing-constructor-of-an-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Note that an anonymous class never has an explicitly declared constructor.  This is quite understandable since if it had one, it would need to have a name and hence no longer be anonymous.

If you want to have an anonymous subclass of a class where the constructor might throw, this is not a problem.

```
class Foo {
    Foo() throws Exception {
    }
}

void demo() throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo() {  // might throw
    };
}
```

Likewise, if you want to initialize the anonymous class with something that might throw, you can do it as well.  Remember that definitions of anonymous classes are expressions so they can throw as long as they are surrounded by a `try`-`catch` block or the containing method declares the exception to be thrown.

```
class Foo {
}

class Bar {
    Bar() throws Exception {
    }
}

void demo() throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();  // might throw
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare a constructor on an anonymous class.

From the Java language specification, section 15.9.5.1, "Anonymous Constructors": An anonymous class cannot have an explicitly declared constructor.

If you need a new constructor, make the class an inner class (but not anonymous) or even a top level class.

Comment: If I still wanted to put it in an anonymous inner class, would I have to use a try/catch block, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: What is the "it" you are referring to?  A constructor?

Comment: Depends on whether your code actually throws or not. Since Foo is declared to throw, you're probably better off with a try / catch block.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to enforce the consistency of instances of an anonymous class, you can create them in a factory method that throws an exception if the arguments are invalid.  This only works for anonymous instances of an interface, since the anonymous class cannot be the return type for a method.

A completely pointless example:

```
public class AnonymousException {

    public static void main(String args) {
        newRunnable(42).run();
    }

    private static Runnable newRunnable(final int x) {
        if(x < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("x=" + x);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to figure out where to put the "throws" to suppress the compiler warning.

There is no way to do that with a `throws`.  The syntax of anonymous does not allow you to put a `throws` clause on the (implicit) constructor.  The (implicit) constructor implicitly throws all of the superclass constructor you are using.  (And that is determined by the number and types of the parameters ...)

Aside: even if it did manage to do that, a `throws` clause doesn't suppress the compilation error I suspect you are getting.  Fundamentally, the superclass constructor declares that it *may* throw `Exception` and adding a `throws` couldn't change that fact ... without there being some way to handle the superclass constructor exception.

> Is there a way to do this without using a try/catch block or making a separate class?

No, there isn't.

And I suspect that what you are trying to do is not even possible with a regular superclass / subclass.  For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(int i) throws Exception { }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar(int i) {
        super(i);
    }
}
```

There is no way to get that to compile because there is no way for the `Bar` constructor to either suppress or handle the exception that the `Foo` constructor declares that it throws.

(And there is a sound reason for this.  If `Foo(42)` did throw an exception, then when the exception reached the `Bar` constructor it would have to deal with the state of a *partially constructed* `Foo`.  This is not practical, and even if it was, it would be a bad idea.)