# java iterator with index parameter

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

hi a normal iterator for a LinkedList would be the following, however, how do we build an iterator that returns an iterator starting at a specified index? How do we build:

```
public Iterator<E>iterator(int index)???
```

thanks!
normal Iterator:

```
    public Iterator<E> iterator( )
    {
        return new ListIterator();
    }

private class ListIterator implements Iterator<E>
    {
        private Node current;

        public ListIterator()
        {
            current = head; // head in the enclosing list
        }
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return current != null;
        }
        public E next()
        {
            E ret = current.item;
            current = current.next;
            return ret;
        }
        public void remove() { /* omitted because optional */ }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't plan to remove elements from your `Colleciton` while iterating, you rather just use a traditional `for` loop.

Comment: LinkedList has a method `listIterator(int)` it does exactly what you want. Here is [link to docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator(int))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could just call the normal `iterator()` method, then call `next()` that many times:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(int index) {
    Iterator<E> iterator = iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < index && iterator.hasNext(); i++) {
        iterator.next();
    }
    return iterator;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you rather just iterate through the collection using a traditional `for` loop and skip the indexes you are not interested in?

Comment: @ChetanKinger: I'm not sure what you mean - this isn't a method I'd usually write, but it answers the question that was asked...

Comment: I'll try to elaborate through code : `for(int i=0;i<collection.size();++i) { if(i>index) { break; }  else { //dosomething } }`. Why create an iterator in the first place? Only reason this would make sense is if you plan to remove elements while iterating.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank u Jon! great help, you are a legend!

Answer (score 2):

This is kick-off example how to implement such `iterator`, but it's advised also to create or extend appropriate `interface` and make this object implementing this `interface` for convention.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class IterableObject {

    private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();


    public Iterator<String> getIterator(final int index) {

        Iterator<String> it = new Iterator<String>() {

            private int current = index;

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public String next() {
                String value = values.get(current);
                current++;
                return value;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if(values.size() > current){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }

            }
        };

        return it;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

According to comments I've written an Iterator for `LinkedList`

```
public Iterator<String> getIterator(final int index) {


        Iterator<String> it = new Iterator<String>() {

            private Object currentObject = null;

            {
                /*initialize block where we traverse linked list 
                  that it will pointed to object at place index*/
                System.out.println("initialize" + currentWord);
                for(int i = 0; currentObject.next != null && i < index; i++, currentObject = currentObject.next)
                    ;

            } 


            @Override
            public void remove() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public String next() {
                Object obj = currentObject.next;
                currentObject = currentObject.next;
                return obj;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return currentObject.next != null;

            }
        };

        return it;
    }
```

Because `Iterator` is object of `Anonymous class` we can't use `constructor` but can initialise it in initialise block look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/362463/947111 We traverse it once at the beginning *(sorry for C style)* so it will point to `currentObject`. All remain code is self explained.

Comment: @ChetanKinger, yes I've made mistake and fixed it already. Thank you for pointing me to that.

Comment: Just tried out your code and it works as advertised. This is a better way to do it than the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: @ChetanKinger, ups I accidentally deleted your comment :( Sorry

Comment: This would be extremely inefficient for a linked list since `values.get(index)` needs to traverse the list from the start every time it is executed to get the specified element.

Comment: The `hasNext` method could be written more succinctly with a body like this: `return values.get(current) != null;`.

Comment: @Lii Still better than the accepted answer as it will perform better in some situations.

Comment: @Lii,  `values.get(current)` throws out of bound exception when its index is greater then size of an internal array.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my comment.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: You're right, it's better for array based lists. But it's really not suitable for linked lists.

Comment: @Anatoly Only moderators can delete comments from other users. I believe I deleted mine accidently :). Also. what @Lii said is an alternate option. `hasNext` could simply return `values.get(current)!=null` but that would require the client code to handle the exception or crash instead. I still prefer your way of doing it.