# Invalid method declaration, return type required in Async Task Context

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I was trying to define a context inside async task but it is returning me below error. Not sure what's wrong with statement

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> getAndroidAdIDtask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        private Context mContext;

        public getAndroidAdIDtask (Context context){
            mContext = context;
        }
```

Here it says "invalid method declaration, return type required"

Can someone help!

Comment: You cannot declare a constructor if you don't extend the `AsyncTask`

Comment: `getAndroidAdIDtask` IS NOT A CONSTRUCTOR

Comment: You shouldn't need to store the context. You have direct access to the Activity from the current class, probably

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing constructor of an anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362424/accessing-constructor-of-an-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 0):

you could pass it as param which is wrong, you should use async task another way.

put the UI relevant code in the `onPostExecute` method. there you also can acces the context.

check this sample [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)